# How to use set /a commands in Batch? It's a very simple game and code

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to use set /a commands to set the value of different variables to bring up later in this game. However, I've tried writing the code several different ways but cmd just closes out after every attempt. What am I doing wrong?

```
:a1-2
cls

echo FINANCIAL MEETING
echo.
echo Secretary of Treasury: Commander %name%! You're here just in time!
echo.
echo We need to cut funding to the military in order to more more evenly
echo.
echo spread out our recources. What would you prefer we cut from?
echo.
echo 1) Weapons
echo.
echo 2) Clothing
echo.
echo 3) Housing
echo.
echo 4) You DARE cut from MY TROOPS?!!
echo.
set /p adec1=

if %adec1% == 1 (
set /a weapons=0
set /a clothing=1
goto poop
)
if %adec1% == 2 (
set /a weapons=1
set /a clothing=0
goto poop
)

:poop
cls

if weapons=1 (
echo Good job sir!
)
if weapons=0 (
echo Oh no!
)
pause
```

Comment: Do not use `Set /P`, which gives you little control over the user input possibilities. When you require only one of a few known inputs, use `Choice` instead. Open a Command Prompt window, (cmd.exe), and enter `Choice /?` to read its usage information. Also `Set /A` is for arithmetic, you're not performing any, so use `Set "weapons=1"`, `Set "clothing=0"` etc. instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

```
if weapons=1 (
...
if weapons=0 (
```

That is ***not*** how you test a value in cmd/batch.
Like most modern languages, equality is tested with `==`.
Batch also allows `equ`.

You also need to wrap your variable in `%`, otherwise you are testing the string-literal `"weapons"` against a number.

You want either `if %weapons%==1 (...)` or `if %weapons% equ 1 (...)`

Comment: C, C++, C#, Python, LUA, Java all use `==` for comparison.   You're right that I typo'd `eq` instead of `equ`, and forgot the `%` wrappers.

Comment: I've never used `==` as a comparison-operator in any of those languages. But then, I've never written any code in those languages, either. Suggest we dispose of these comments pronto.

Comment: *"I've never written any code in those languages"*  - That explains a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
if %adec1% == 2 (
set /a weapons=1
set /a clothing=0
goto poop
)


if weapons=1 (
echo Good job sir!
)
```

Can you spot the difference between these snippets?

In the first, the syntax `%varname%` is used to access the *value* of the variable. In the second... the literal `weapons` is compared to `1` - or would be had you used the correct comparison operator (``` ==`` or ```equ`)

`cmd` attempts to make sense of `if weapons=1 (` and is actually quite happy with `if weapons=1` - that, it decides is a string. Then it looks for a comparison-operator and doesn't understand `(` as that's not a valid comparison-operator.

If you were to run the batch from the command-prompt rather than clicking a shortcut, then `cmd` will reciprocate by showing you an error message.